# How to program three.js TrackballControls after setting camera position

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am developing a game using threejs editor.
When game starts, I set camera position:

```
function setCameraPos(Camera,myColor){
    if(myColor=="Red"){
      Camera.position.x=3.74;
      Camera.position.y=19.5;
      Camera.position.z=1.54;

      Camera.rotation.x=-1.57;
      Camera.rotation.y=-0.12;
      Camera.rotation.z=-1.57;
    }
    CONTROLS = new THREE.TrackballControls( Camera );
}
```

Then in loop: This isn't working the way I want. This changes camera position to a default TrackballControls position.

```
function update( event ) {
    if(startGame == true) {
        CONTROLS.update();
    }
}
```

I want to first set a camera position, then simple apply zoom in/out on it using TrackballControls

Comment: you're declaring CONTROLS locally within the function setCameraPos - so it won't be available to other functions. Try declaring CONTROLS as a global variable => https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp